# What is the logic behind the prometheus sum after rate functionality?

Tags: sum, grafana, prometheus, rate

In about two minutes I have 2000 requests - which should be 1000 requests/minute or 17 requests/second.

The total counter works fine and gives me a nice graph:

```
sum by(status_code) (     request_duration_count{service_id="myserviceId", path=~".*myservice/frag/.*"}     )
```

The request rate results in a flatline at 0:

```
sum by(status_code) (rate(request_duration_count{service_id="myserviceId", path=~".*myservice/frag/.*"}[1m]))
```

I think problem here is that I have one request per URL - which is not fine but it is as it is.

The URLs look like this:

```
https://myserver/myservice/frag/1
https://myserver/myservice/frag/2
https://myserver/myservice/frag/3
https://myserver/myservice/frag/4
https://myserver/myservice/frag/5
...
```

Each of these URLs are set to the "path" label and so I get 2000 series for this metric.

So if I calculate the rate over one minute I get 0,008 requests per second for each series.

If I sum this up (0,008... * 2000) I should get roundabout 17.

So why do I have a flatline at zero?

Comment: Your first query doesn't have a `rate()` in it, it's just showing the sum of all the counter time series, that doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Oliver This was not my question. The first one exactly does what I want - in case of the first graph...

Comment: Sure, i was just wondering what the first one was about. At any rate, you should try to reduce the cardinality of your `path` label (either within the app or via label rewriting and recording rules), high cardinality of label values isn't handled well by Prometheus.